# How to add total margins to a dataframe

Tags: r

I want to add total margins to my data frame. The total for each year (row total) and the total for each column (from 23 to 42) and the grand total.

```
   structure(list(`Identifiant de l'hôpital` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1), Année = c("2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", 
    "2020"), `23` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `24` = c(0L, 2L, 
    8L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 3L), `25` = c(2L, 11L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 5L), `26` = c(5L, 
    8L, 11L, 10L, 8L, 13L, 1L), `27` = c(3L, 16L, 8L, 14L, 14L, 7L, 
    3L), `28` = c(7L, 8L, 9L, 16L, 8L, 7L, 0L), `29` = c(4L, 3L, 
    10L, 16L, 14L, 13L, 2L), `30` = c(5L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 4L, 11L, 2L
    ), `31` = c(7L, 15L, 8L, 15L, 12L, 9L, 3L), `32` = c(8L, 18L, 
    13L, 19L, 23L, 17L, 11L), `33` = c(7L, 11L, 20L, 24L, 13L, 12L, 
    6L), `34` = c(9L, 12L, 10L, 24L, 12L, 24L, 5L), `35` = c(5L, 
    18L, 22L, 28L, 16L, 22L, 5L), `36` = c(7L, 31L, 28L, 21L, 24L, 
    21L, 12L), `37` = c(3L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 31L, 27L, 9L), `38` = c(14L, 
    31L, 45L, 27L, 30L, 35L, 12L), `39` = c(17L, 33L, 46L, 37L, 32L, 
    44L, 14L), `40` = c(13L, 51L, 41L, 46L, 51L, 48L, 16L), `41` = c(15L, 
    26L, 31L, 27L, 27L, 40L, 20L), `42` = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    0L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -7L), groups = structure(list(`Identifiant de l'hôpital` = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Année = c("2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", 
    "2018", "2019", "2020"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
        5L, 6L, 7L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -7L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way with base R. (FYI, your data is grouped, so I `ungroup` it; without doing that, the `rbind` portion fails.)

```r
out <- cbind(rbind(ungroup(dat)[,1:2], NA), addmargins(as.matrix(dat[,-(1:2)])))
rownames(out) <- NULL
out
#   Identifiant de l'hôpital Année 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31  32 33 34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41 42  Sum
# 1                        1  2014  0  0  2  5  3  7  4  5  7   8  7  9   5   7   3  14  17  13  15  2  133
# 2                        1  2015  0  2 11  8 16  8  3  9 15  18 11 12  18  31  21  31  33  51  26  1  325
# 3                        1  2016  0  8  9 11  8  9 10 10  8  13 20 10  22  28  21  45  46  41  31  2  352
# 4                        1  2017  3  8  8 10 14 16 16  8 15  19 24 24  28  21  21  27  37  46  27  1  373
# 5                        1  2018  0  9  7  8 14  8 14  4 12  23 13 12  16  24  31  30  32  51  27  2  337
# 6                        1  2019  0  4  8 13  7  7 13 11  9  17 12 24  22  21  27  35  44  48  40  3  365
# 7                        1  2020  0  3  5  1  3  0  2  2  3  11  6  5   5  12   9  12  14  16  20  0  129
# 8                       NA  <NA>  3 34 50 56 65 55 62 49 69 109 93 96 116 144 133 194 223 266 186 11 2014
```

Answer (score 3):

Here in one way to use the `dplyr` package. `dat2` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(RowSum = rowSums(select(., `23`:`42`))) %>%
  bind_rows(., summarize(., across(`23`:RowSum, .fns = sum)))
```

Answer (score 2):

With janitor:

```r
library(janitor)

adorn_totals(df, where = c("row", "col"))

#>  Identifiant de l'hôpital Année 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31  32 33 34  35  36
#>                         1  2014  0  0  2  5  3  7  4  5  7   8  7  9   5   7
#>                         1  2015  0  2 11  8 16  8  3  9 15  18 11 12  18  31
#>                         1  2016  0  8  9 11  8  9 10 10  8  13 20 10  22  28
#>                         1  2017  3  8  8 10 14 16 16  8 15  19 24 24  28  21
#>                         1  2018  0  9  7  8 14  8 14  4 12  23 13 12  16  24
#>                         1  2019  0  4  8 13  7  7 13 11  9  17 12 24  22  21
#>                         1  2020  0  3  5  1  3  0  2  2  3  11  6  5   5  12
#>                     Total     -  3 34 50 56 65 55 62 49 69 109 93 96 116 144
#>   37  38  39  40  41 42 Total
#>    3  14  17  13  15  2   133
#>   21  31  33  51  26  1   325
#>   21  45  46  41  31  2   352
#>   21  27  37  46  27  1   373
#>   31  30  32  51  27  2   337
#>   27  35  44  48  40  3   365
#>    9  12  14  16  20  0   129
#>  133 194 223 266 186 11  2014
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>